# windows RDP when not logged on

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I normally use my windows laptop by RDPing into it.   which works great 99% of the time.

until I reboot the machine.

Then for some reason I can't RDP into the box until I've first manually logged into it at least once.  I suspect some RDP service is only starting when I first login - but I don't know how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as, given I don't actually directly use the laptop for anything, it's folded up and plugged in in a holder - and so logging into it manually is way harder than it sounds.

(windows 10)

Comment: You can do this via an alternative.  Mount Radmin Server on the Laptop (modest one time license cost) and put Radmin Viewer on the accessing machine (freee).  You can restart the laptop and re-access with Radmin Viewer.  Works fine.  I use it.

Comment: hmm.. I'm fairly confident my system administrators would have a heart attack if I installed something like that on the work laptop.   also I really like the RDP experience.